# The python natu units package does not simplify commutatively

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

I have a problem with how the python natu package simplifies the display unit. As the following example shows, it depends on the order:

```
from natu.units import Mm, km, s

print(1 * Mm / km * s)
>>> 1000 s

print(1 * Mm * s / km)
>>>> 1 Mm*s/km
```

I would like it second case to look like the first.
I tried

```
from natu import config
config.simplification_level = 2
```

but that does not seem to help. The situation is the same with other units.

Answer: It seems that the package performs some simplification before storing the display_unit:

```
from natu.units import Mm, km, s
(1 * Mm / km * s).display_unit
>>> s
(1 * Mm * s / km).display_unit
>>> Mm*s/km
```

My solution is to explicitely set the quantities' display unit.

Comment: Do you have a question or is this just an observation?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. The question was "How to make the second case look like the first". I found a workaround and added it in post.